# Authentication middleware is called for routes that don't exist

Tags: node.js, express

I have public and private routes in an app.

```js
// public
router.use(publicRoute);

// After this all Routes are private
router.use(runAsyncWrapper(isAuthenticated));

// private
router.use(privateRoute);
```

There is also a route that matches all possible routes, and returns a 404 error.

```js
app.all('*', (req, res, next) => {
  next(new MyError(`Route ${req.originalUrl} doesn not exist.`));
});
```

In the middleware I try to authenticate the user.

```js
const isAuthenticated = async (req, res, next) => {
  const {
    headers: { authorization },
  } = req;

  const user = await tryToAuthenticateAndReturnUser(authorization);

  if (!user) throw new MyError('Token is not valid', 401);

  req.user = user;

  next();
};
```

This middleware is run for any route that doesn't match any public route, even if the route itself doesn't exist. So if I request a route that doesn't exist, instead of 404 error it will return me the `"Token is not valid", 401` error.

How do I make it return the right error, 404 if route doesn't exist, and 401 if route exists but user can't be authenticated?

Comment: Order of middlewares matter. You have to use your errorhandler or notfound handler first, everthing should come after that

Comment: @kmp, no, you are wrong, not found handler should go after other routes. Otherwise all the routes added after not found handler will be ignored.

Comment: Then another solution could be to put this isAuthenticated middleware directly on your controllers. Example `router.get('/some-route', isAuthentiacted, (req, res, next) => { /* do something */ })`

Answer (score 0):

I had to add the middleware for every route separately, as @kmp answered in the comments to my question. I could improve it a little bit, by adding middleware to routes using first word in routes' path.

For example, if we have such routes

```js
GET `/users` //to get all users
POST `/users` //to create a user

GET `/posts/:userId` //to get posts of a user
POST `/posts/:userId` //to create a user's post
```

We can create an array like this

```js
const protectedRoutes = ['/users', '/posts'];
```

and then add authentication middleware like this

```js
protectedRoutes.forEach(route => router.use(route, runAsyncWrapper(isAuthenticated)))
```

After this every route that starts with `/users` or `/posts` will be protected.